# Use Different Names for Table Column and Property

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have a column in parse named `description` and as you know this is a reserved keyword in iOS. Hence I cannot use the same name for the corresponding `@property` in my code.

Is there a way to map the value of that column to a property with a different name (e.g. `@NSManaged var menuItemDescription: String`)?

The other obvious option would be to rename the column to something else, but this leaks my iOS implementation details to my back-end, which is not ideal.

Comment: description is a reserved word?  Is that a swift thing?  Can we see the line that isn't compiling?

Comment: You can use description.

Comment: It seems like you are correct, description is not a keyword. However it is in objective-c and I would like to avoid it (if possible) to prevent unpredictable behavior. Most libraries are still written in obj. c and their behavior will be unpredictable if I use it. Right?

Comment: Your property will not affect the available Objective-C description property of `NSObject` class.

Comment: Are you sure? Not saying I don't trust you, but has Apple explicitly mentioned this anywhere? Wouldn't want to get a nasty surprise

Comment: If you're using `@NSManaged` that implies that you're doing Core Data mapping - right? Apple explicitly discourage overloading `description` when dealing with Core Data - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdManagedObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003397-SW7